# Como regresar al main cuando haya un error?

Tags: java

Quiero que cuando haya un error por la introduccion de datos del usuario, le vuelva a pedir los datos hasta que esten bien.

```
public class EntradaDeDatos {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
        int edad=0;

        System.out.println("Introduce tu Nombre, Edad y Fecha de nacimiento");

        String nombre=entrada.next();

        try{
        edad=entrada.nextInt();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Debes de escribir un numero y no una letra ");//////**aqui quiero que regrese a pedirle los datos**
        }

        String fechan=entrada.next();

        System.out.println("Tu nombre:"+nombre+"\n Tu Edad"+edad+"\n Tu Fecha de nacimiento"+fechan);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa una variable bandera `datoCorrecto` que inicializas a verdadero cada vez que se va a introducir datos. Mete la introducción de datos en un bucle do-while que se repita mientras `datoCorrecto` sea falso. Y si salta la excepción pon `datoCorrecto` a falso.

Tal que así :

```
int edad=0;
boolean datoCorrecto;
do {
    datoCorrecto = true;  

    System.out.println("Introduce tu Edad");

    try{
        edad=entrada.nextInt();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Debes de escribir un numero y no una letra ");
        datoCorrecto = false;
    }
} while( !datoCorrecto);
```

El código anterior solo sirve para el caso de la edad. Usándo código similar al anterior puedes resolverlo para edad, nombre y fecha.

Comment: Gracias! Muy Claro!

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar algo como así como lo siguiente. Intenta usar siempre métodos y en el main mandar a llamarlos; cada método debería tener su propia lógica de manejo de errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, es preferible en la medida de lo posible que deje un log de texto y no una imagen del mismo, pues hace mas fácil su lectura para los usuarios, puede ver compartir, editar, cerrar, reportar, pudiendo acceder a editar presionado sobre el, y cambiando la imagen por el log de texto. Saludos

Comment: Me gusta esta respuesta, si estuviese en texto le daba un +1.

Comment: Hola, yo también te invito a agregar el código. Saludos.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es porqué me dan -1 -.- De hecho creo que es la primera o segunda respuesta que hago y luego luego -1. No entiendo. La imagen no creo que sea tanto problema, son muy pocas líneas como para no poder copiarlas.